# Java application crash with drawString

Tags: java, crash, jvm

I have a problem with my Java application. Sometimes my application crashes for unknown reasons.

I have replicated the problem and the indicted method seems to be

```
g.drawString(s, CELL_WIDTH + c * CELL_WIDTH, y)
```

It's very strange, however, that is not generated any JVM crash file (hs_pid.log...) neither errors are reported in console window although I use the following command line options

```
-verbose:gc -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/root/TEST -XX:ErrorFile=/root/TEST/vmlogs%p.log -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/root/TEST -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:/root/TEST/gc.log
```

Below you can find a small test case that reproduce the problem by emphasizing it

`Thread.sleep (1)`

Launch the program and after 5-6 hours (more o less) the problem is reproduced.

I run the application on Linux PC with Java 1.7.0_80 (the latest version of Java 7 family) and I reproduced the same problem also with the latest of Java 6.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class TestDraw {

  private static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 800;

  private static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 480;

  private static final String AB = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-:?$";

  private static Random rnd = new Random();

  private static final Font m_font = new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 22);

  private static final int NUM_ROWS = 17;

  private static final int CELL_WIDTH = 12;

  private static final int ROW_HEIGTH = 25;

  private static final int ROW_WIDTH = WINDOW_WIDTH;

  private static String randomString(int len) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      sb.append(AB.charAt(rnd.nextInt(AB.length())));
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    JLabel textLabel = new JLabel() {
      @Override
      protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        for (int i = 0; i <= NUM_ROWS; i++) {
          int y_text = (i + 1) * ROW_HEIGTH - 7;
          String text = randomString(64);
          drawString(text, y_text, g, Color.black);
        }
      }

      private void drawString(String text, int y, Graphics g, Color color) {
        for (int c = 0; c < text.length(); c++) {
          String s = text.substring(c, c + 1);
          g.drawString(s, CELL_WIDTH + c * CELL_WIDTH, y);
        }
      }
    };

    JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("TEST COMPONENT");
    myFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    myFrame.setResizable(false);

    myFrame.add(textLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    myFrame.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    myFrame.setVisible(true);
    myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    textLabel.setFont(m_font);

    while (true) {
      textLabel.repaint();
      try {
        Thread.sleep(1);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

I changed test case with @Hovercraft Full Of Eels suggestions.

This is the modify:

```
textLabel.setFont(m_font);
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        while (true) {
          textLabel.repaint();
          try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }
    });
    t.start();
  }
```

---

I have update my test case adding the suggestion of @apangin and I call this method inside the main.

```
  private static void attachShutDownHook() {
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        System.out.println("Inside Shutdown Hook");
      }
    });
    System.out.println("Shut Down Hook Attached.");
  }
```

The result are that application crash always but the

```
   System.out.println("Inside Shutdown Hook");
```

isn't called.

Instead if I kill Java process manually the previous print is called.

---

I have modify my test case according @Hovercraft Full Of Eels suggestion. Now I am not using while true and thread.sleep but swing timer to queuing the Swing code on the event thread. The test case crash always.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TestDraw {
  private static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 800;

  private static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 480;

  private static final String AB = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-:?$";

  private static Random rnd = new Random();

  private static final Font m_font = new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 22);

  private static final int NUM_ROWS = 17;

  private static final int CELL_WIDTH = 12;

  private static final int ROW_HEIGTH = 25;

  private static final int ROW_WIDTH = WINDOW_WIDTH;

  private static Timer updateTimer = null;

  private static JLabel textLabel = null;

  private static String randomString(int len) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      sb.append(AB.charAt(rnd.nextInt(AB.length())));
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    textLabel = new JLabel() {
      @Override
      protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        for (int i = 0; i <= NUM_ROWS; i++) {
          int y_text = (i + 1) * ROW_HEIGTH - 7;
          String text = randomString(64);
          drawString(text, y_text, g, Color.black);
        }
      }

      private void drawString(String text, int y, Graphics g, Color color) {
        for (int c = 0; c < text.length(); c++) {
          String s = text.substring(c, c + 1);
          g.drawString(s, CELL_WIDTH + c * CELL_WIDTH, y);
        }
      }
    };

    updateTimer = new Timer(1, new ActionListener() {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        textLabel.repaint();
      }
    });

    JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("TEST COMPONENT");
    myFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    myFrame.setResizable(false);

    myFrame.add(textLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    myFrame.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    myFrame.setVisible(true);
    myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    textLabel.setFont(m_font);
    updateTimer.start();

  }

}
```

Comment: You should use a Swing Timer, not a while true or Thread.sleep, and you should take care that all Swing code is started on the event thread.

Comment: While(true) is only used to demonstrate the problem. In my real application I don't use while(true) but this kind operation are performed in a separated thread/timer.

Comment: Regardless, this: `"Sometimes my application crashes for unknown reasons."` -- likely means one thing -- you've got a threading error, and since this is a Swing application, the first thing I'd do would be to make sure that my app obeys all Swing threading rule.

Comment: In your opinion, this test application violates some swing rules?

Comment: Absolutely it does. You're using while true and thread.sleep, you're not queuing the Swing code on the event thread.

Comment: Ok, I prepare a new test case with timer/thread and try to reproduce the problem

Comment: How does 'crash' look like, does the application silently terminate? It may be helpful to check the following things: 1) the process exit code; 2) whether ShutdownHooks are executed; 3) intercept native `_exit` call by setting a breakpoint in gdb or by overriding `exit` with LD_PRELOAD trick.

Comment: 1) the process exit code is Exit 1
2) I have tried whit ShutdownHooks but it isn't called.
3a) I launch my application with eclipse debugger but no exception is catched.
3b) How can I overriding exit with LD_PRELOAD trick with java source code?